# Missing 1.6% of expected area after buffering SpatialPoints from vector of widths

Tags: r, buffer, rgeos

Goal: I am buffering a random set of points (i.e. centroids) with different widths from a vector of predefined areas to make a random null model of polygons in a given extent. I am iterating through a 1000 object list go generate the distribution, but have provided an example for only one object since my issue occurs at that level.

Issue: The total area of the buffered centroids is 32.19617 *hectares* less than the original total area.

Question: How is this area being cut? I feel like I am missing something about how `gBuffer()` works. I thought it might be a planar vs geodesic issue, but read that `regeos` will only handle projected spatial objects (which I have). It doesn't seem like a rounding issue because the difference is spread across 101 points (0.318774 *hectares* per point). Any suggestions for how else to troubleshoot?

*The coordinate system used is NAD 1983 Albers. The PROJ.4 projection string is:*
*"+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000
+datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0*

**Example**

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

#the predefined areas
areas <- c(21.92466, 0.13743, 22.4576, 3.10855, 13.33003, 19.6971, 8.65893, 
           1.36051, 1.97611, 0.4128, 5.09534, 13.08232, 0.65519, 6.69976, 
           1.31828, 61.96348, 2.55861, 98.36752, 17.00504, 35.09418, 63.48043, 
           15.28773, 9.96236, 0.75299, 7.92188, 9.88541, 1.44117, 9.31345, 
           0.83406, 113.84276, 4.55541, 4.61159, 4.3415, 0.78915, 11.73815, 
           0.59766, 0.94186, 9.81746, 30.88698, 3.93619, 1.50583, 39.07577, 
           33.18197, 39.31604, 29.86065, 6.17087, 66.89905, 4.66883, 64.63708, 
           2.83463, 38.12346, 14.0179, 25.69435, 26.97518, 26.86608, 8.11912, 
           32.90833, 47.68297, 7.36192, 0.8557, 1.35078, 33.75896, 4.10684, 
           1.33971, 26.18847, 1.68767, 34.18756, 18.59203, 4.13611, 23.08783, 
           27.20771, 0.63805, 16.71614, 10.73375, 15.9914, 61.96926, 8.12024, 
           1.26379, 14.14531, 11.27807, 9.35613, 5.94766, 92.88387, 17.1014, 
           4.05735, 15.91729, 10.92878, 3.23904, 4.15417, 59.53967, 0.41474, 
           6.3664, 16.00491, 0.72044, 14.36096, 1.10064, 2.52104, 6.35359, 
           33.68302, 176.33294, 12.89539)

#don't know how to code SpatialPolygonsDataFrame for reproduciblity, but it can be downloaded at link below
extent <- readOGR(dsn = "SanDiegoCounty.shp", layer = "SanDiegoCounty") 

#sample points within the extent equal to the total number in 'areas'
centroids <- spsample(x = extent, n = length(areas), type = "random") 

#buffer centroids with width derived from predefined areas vector
buffered.centroids <- gBuffer(spgeom = centroids, byid = TRUE, id = names(centroids), width = sqrt(areas/pi))

#the total predefined area: 1966.97647
sum(areas) 

#the total area of buffered centroids: 1934.78029709348
buffered.centroid.area <- sum(sapply(X = buffered.centroids@polygons, FUN = function(z){sum(z@area)}))

#difference in total areas: 32.1961729065185
sum(areas)-buffered.centroid.area
```

Link to `extent` shapefile on Google Drive: [extent.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6b31JC-7nhzW_WBQX8A2LO7CRuKxguS)

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the units of the areas, and the coordinate system (.prj) of the data file.

Comment: Possibly different vertices that make up the boundaries. They can affect the area calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @obrl_soil is spot on. If you want to increase `gBuffer`'s approximation of circles, you can increase `quadsegs`. Here is a table of these errors:

```
library(rgeos)
p0 <- readWKT("POINT(0 0)")
pe <- c()
for(qs in 1:20) {
    pe[qs] <- 100 * (1.0 - gArea(gBuffer(p0, quadsegs=qs)) / pi)
    message(sprintf("quadsegs=%d : error=%.3g%%", qs, pe[qs]))
}
plot(1:20, pe, "b", xlab="quadsegs")

# Shows these messages ... and plot
quadsegs=1 : error=36.3%
quadsegs=2 : error=9.97%
quadsegs=3 : error=4.51%
quadsegs=4 : error=2.55%
quadsegs=5 : error=1.64%
quadsegs=6 : error=1.14%
quadsegs=7 : error=0.837%
quadsegs=8 : error=0.641%
quadsegs=9 : error=0.507%
quadsegs=10 : error=0.411%
quadsegs=11 : error=0.34%
quadsegs=12 : error=0.285%
quadsegs=13 : error=0.243%
quadsegs=14 : error=0.21%
quadsegs=15 : error=0.183%
quadsegs=16 : error=0.161%
quadsegs=17 : error=0.142%
quadsegs=18 : error=0.127%
quadsegs=19 : error=0.114%
quadsegs=20 : error=0.103%
```

[image]

Two things you can see here is that the error for quadsegs=5 is 1.64%, and that the error levels off near 0.1% at quadsegs=20. You can push this to a crazy quadsegs=1000 to get 0.0000411%, if you really want, but you can't get exactly 0% error that you would expect from perfect circle buffers.

Comment: very useful addition! I've added some comparative speed tests as well.

Answer (score 2):

gBuffer on points won't generate a true circle by default, but rather a regular 20-sided polygon (the setting 'quadsegs' is relevant here and defaults to 5). As the wiki article for [Icosagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosagon) points out, the area of such a shape is very slightly smaller than the true circle that contains it.

If its important to get closer to a perfect circle, try increasing quadsegs to 10 or even 20, but bear in mind that performance will be affected:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

# 1000 random points
pts <- matrix(c(replicate(2, sample(10000, size = 1000, replace = FALSE))),
              ncol = 2, byrow = F)
pts <- st_multipoint(pts)
pts <- st_sfc(pts)
pts <- st_cast(pts, 'POINT')
pts_sp <- as(pts, 'Spatial')

# 1. test speed as quadsegs increases in gBuffer
test_rg <- microbenchmark(
  "5"  = gBuffer(pts_sp),
  "10" = gBuffer(pts_sp, quadsegs = 10),
  "20" = gBuffer(pts_sp, quadsegs = 20),
  "50" = gBuffer(pts_sp, quadsegs = 50)
)

# 2. test equivalent function in sf package
test_sf <- microbenchmark(
  "5"  = st_buffer(pts, dist = 1, nQuadSegs = 5),
  "10" = st_buffer(pts, dist = 1, nQuadSegs = 10),
  "20" = st_buffer(pts, dist = 1, nQuadSegs = 20),
  "50" = st_buffer(pts, dist = 1, nQuadSegs = 50)
)

ggplot() +
  stat_summary(data = test_rg, 
               aes(x = expr, y = time/1000000, group = 1, colour = 'red'),
               size = 1.2, fun.y = 'median', geom = 'line') +
  stat_summary(data = test_sf, 
               aes(x = expr, y = time/1000000, group = 1, colour = 'blue'), 
               size = 1.2, fun.y = 'median', geom = 'line') +
  labs(x = 'n quadsegs', y = 'milliseconds') +
  ggtitle('Buffer function speed comparison', 
          subtitle = '1000 points, 100 runs, buffer dist 1') +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'package::function', 
                      values = c('blue'='blue','red'='red'), 
                      labels = c('sf::st_buffer','rgeos::gBuffer'),
                      guide = 'legend')
```

[image]

sf and rgeos wrap the same C++ library so results will be identical. Note that rgeos::gBuffer defaults to 5 quadsegs, while sf::st_buffer defaults to 30, so the latter package sacrifices some speed for accuracy by default. sf's inherent speed advantage offsets that somewhat.